# Is this use of "have" correct?

Tags: grammar, usage

We use *has* with plural person as well as non living things. *(please correct me, if I'm wrong)* and we use *have* with singular person like I, we, you, they.

I often find sentences like;

> Though poverty is still rampant in India, economic growth and commercial development **have served to reduce it** substantially over the years

Why do they use *have* and not *has*?

Answer (score 3):

Edit: you are saying the opposite of every English language book. Actually, *has* is singular, and *have* is plural! (in the third person, that is.)

Your sentence has a plural subject: *economic growth **and** commercial development*.

Because of that, the verb also takes the plural.

When you use *A and B* as the subject, it is *plural*.

Consider the following sentences:

> *Alice* **has** a book.
>   *Bob* **likes** reading.

Now, with *and*, we get the plural:

> *Alice and Bob* **have** a book.
>   *Alice and Bob* **like** reading.

Answer (score 0):

> We use has with plural person [...].

Could you provide an example for this? I cannot think of what you could mean.

Additionally, they and we are referring to more than one person, i.e. plural. The only exception here is "I have", other than that it is " has" and " have".

Concerning your sentence, "growth and development" can be shortened to "they", hence "They have served...".